# Probability that any two out of three numbers match.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I need to calculate the probability that any two out of three numbers match. Each number lies in the interval [1:10] and is chosen randomly. For example: There are three people, each of them can choose an integer from 1 to 10. What is the probability that at least two people chose the same numbers. The first person chooses a random number, the second person has a 1/10 chance of choosing the same number, the third person has a 2/10 chance of choosing at least one identical number with the other two. And the mysterious probability will be 3/10. Here are my thoughts on the matter. If I understand correctly, it's a 3/10?

Answer (score 2):

The probability that all the three numbers are different is $\frac{10\times9\times8}{10^3}=\frac{18}{25}.$

Can you see why?

Comment: Then the probability that at least two numbers match is 0.28. True?

Comment: @RomanParkhomenko $1-\frac{18}{25}=0.28$